# Raycast is not detecting imported fbx on mouseclick

Tags: three.js, raycasting

I’m importing an .fbx file containing four meshes. For some reason, I can’t get a raycast intersect with any of the meshes. I’ve had success with detection of THREE-generated geometry, but no results on the import. Here’s the code…

```
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        camera.position.y = 50;
        camera.position.z = 50;
        
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        
        let meshes = [];
        window.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick, true);
        
        const loader = new FBXLoader();
        
        // fbx file is four meshes imported as single file
        loader.load('/models/aromator.fbx', (object) => {
            object.traverse(function(child){
                if(child.isMesh){
                    meshes.push(child);
                }
            })
        scene.add(object);
        
        //"meshes" array logs as four meshes
        
        const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        const cursor = new THREE.Vector2();

        let active = false;
        
        function onMouseClick(event){
            cursor.x = (event.clientX/window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            cursor.y = (event.clientY/window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
            console.log("mouse clicked");
            
            clickParts();
        }
        
        // nothing happens when this function is called
        function clickParts(){
            raycaster.setFromCamera(cursor, camera);
            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(meshes);
            console.log(intersects.length); // this returns zero
            if(intersects.length > 0){
                if(active){
                    console.log(intersects[0].name);
                }
            }
            active = false;
        }
        
        const animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        };

        animate();
```

I'm new to Three.js, so I suspect I'm making an elementary mistake.  Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you fix your code sample? You open brackets with `loader.load({` then `object.traverse({ ... })` but you never close the loader's set of brackets.

Comment: It also looks like you need to add a `-` symbol to your `cursor.y` calculations, [like in this example](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster)

Comment: The close brackets mistake just happened as I was copying the code to paste in the query.  HOWEVER, missing the minus sign before the cursor.y calculation was the problem.  Many thanks, Marquizzo!